# CSS: Varying Rotation on Wordpress site?

Tags: css, rotation

I did try a all sort of codes but i can't seem to get it right.
What i like to see is that the different posts with thumbnail have different degrees for rotation.

Here is the css code that i tryed:

```
.hentry .post-thumb li:nth-child(2n){
    -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
    transform: rotate(3deg);
}

.hentry .post-thumb li:nth-child(3n){
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
```

You can see the site [here](http://www.kinderkleding112.nl).

Thanks

Comment: Seems to work for me in Chrome/Firefox

Comment: Opera works, too. What is the browser you're using?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS you provide in your question doesn't match the HTML on the site you're linking to. There's no `li` descendent of a `.post-thumb` element.

I think you misunderstand how the [`nth-child()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) works, though. You should be doing something like this:

```
.hentry:nth-child(2n) .post-thumb img { transform: rotate(3deg); /* etc. */ }
.hentry:nth-child(3n) .post-thumb img { transform: rotate(-3deg); /* etc. */ }
```

This will rotate the thumbnails of every second post 3 degrees to the right (i.e. the 2nd, 4th, 6th etc. child of the `.posts` div), and all thumbnails of every third post 3 degrees to the left (i.e. the 3rd, 6th, 9th etc. child of the `.posts` div).

I'm not sure if `2n` and `3n` are quite the expression you intend either, though. Perhaps [Sitepoint's "Understanding :nth-child Pseudo-class Expressions"](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/understandingnthchildexpressions) will help.